# Should I install a dedicated earth connection for an antenna?

Tags: antenna, grounding

I was tasked with installing a point to point antenna on a monument. I have read in the dish's manual that it should be connected to earth for optimal performance.

My problem is the power that goes into the monument does not have a ground wire. The monument's wiring source is 200 meters away. In that service I can tap the ground from there but the civil works required just to run a ground wire from there is enormous so I am looking for alternatives.

Would it be okay for me to place a ground rod on the monuments location and tap the ground from there? Would it be as effective?

[image]

Comment: For lightning and static protection, you need to ground the metallic antenna mount, and a ground rod close to the base of the monument is best. But grounding of the AC power and connected equipment is a separate issue that should be addressed by an electrician.

Comment: You should consult an electrician. The last thing you want is an installation that is not made up to your local electrical codes and will be dangerous to people.

Comment: Please link the dish's manual

Comment: @Andyaka There will be several antenna installed, this is one of them on [page 8](https://static.tp-link.com/upload/manual/2022/202212/20221206/7106509995_CPE510_IG_V1.pdf)

Comment: @Justme I actually did this, and i asked two electrician from the electric company both of which gave me contradicting answers. So what is the worst i can do here?, The atenna is plastic , and is attached to cement so there is no metal that is exposed. The only thing thats metal is the control box itself. Even the powersupplies of the antenna is plastic (housed inside the metal control box)

Comment: @MarkLeavitt There is no metallic mount , maybe the strap but thats it, the strap is mounted on cement, and the antenna is basically covered in plastic. I have doubts on the electricians i have talked to, hence im here asking to get a general idea.

Comment: It looks from the installation manual that the ground is required only if you are using unshielded CAT5 cable to connect from the POE supply to the CPE. The ground connection is therefore intended for EMI mitigation, so that the CPE has an RF ground reference, and not for electrical safety reasons.